# Flask SQLAlchemy, '__init__ takes exactly one argument' when adding database record via class constructor

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In my API I often use a pattern like this:

```
from app.models import Timecards

def add_timecard(payload):
    new_timecard = Timecards(**payload)
    db.session.add(new_timecard)
    db.session.commit()
```

Where `Timecards` is:

```
class Timecards(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "timesheet_line"

    id = db.Column("line_id", db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    description = db.Column("line_description", db.String(255))
    ref_number = db.Column("line_ref_number", db.String(255))
    notes = db.Column("line_notes", db.String(255))
    approved_by_id = db.Column("line_approved_by_id", db.String(255))
    date_approved = db.Column("line_date_approved", db.DateTime)
    date_submitted = db.Column("line_date_submitted", db.DateTime)
    time_started = db.Column("line_time_started", db.DateTime)
    time_ended = db.Column("line_time_ended", db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column("line_user_id", db.Integer)
    is_active = db.Column("line_isActive", db.Integer)
```

I do not have a custom `__init__` method defined on this class. All my other classes  work perfectly fine when I interact with them this way but for some reason this particular class seems to be only accept this automatically passed `self` argument and rejects my `payload` with the error

```
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

For example I have this class:

```
class ServicesRendered(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "services_rendered"

    id = db.Column("service_id", db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    notes = db.Column("service_notes", db.String(255))
    status = db.Column("service_status", db.String(255))
    time_open = db.Column("service_timeOpen", db.DateTime)
    time_close = db.Column("service_timeClose", db.DateTime)
    is_active = db.Column("service_isActive", db.Integer)
```

and the following code works perfectly:

```
def add_services_rendered(payload):
    new_services_rendered = ServicesRendered(**payload)
```

As far as I can tell these classes are defined in the same way, and I am interacting with them in the same way, but one throws an error and the other does not.

Comment: Can you show us how you're instantiating `Timecards` to get the error? Are you using the `**` to explode `payload`?

Comment: its in the first block of code, `Timecards(**payload)`

Comment: Ah, sorry 'bout that, scanned right past it. What's in `payload`? The error says only 2 parameters were supplied (one of which is `self`, as you pointed out), does `payload` contain only one element?

Comment: Please include the full trace back in your question.

Comment: In your second example, `payload` must be an empty dictionary, in your first, it's not. You are calling `__init__(self, <whatever payload explotes into>)` and the method is defined as `__init__(self)`. That's why you're getting the error.

Comment: `payload must be an empty dictionary` this is not true, I solved the issue already though thanks

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak could you please point out what the solution was? maybe self-answer your question? I have the same issue... thanks

Comment: man I normally always do leave answers in these situations, not sure why I haven't here. I honestly don't remember the solution, but I'm fairly certain the  problem was in the payload and not in any of my sqlalchemy code. Sorry I can't be of more help